# Why is app size higher in Redmi Phones (MIUI phones)

Tags: android, redmi-device

**Left Image:** App size from Nexus 6P running Android 7.1.1 - **13.22 MB**

**Right Image:** App size from Redmi 3S Prime running Android 6.0 with MIUI - **21.27 MB**

Why is this difference in size? This screenshot is taken just after installing the app. (so no data is populated since I haven't opened the app).

Our apk size is **6.7MB**

[image]       
[image]